# How to clear a row when a specific cell changes in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet where:
C3 is the cell I am entering a name & based on the name my team is voting YES/ NO on the cell D5: D20.
Now when I am changing the name from C3 their votes still on the page. I want to clear their cells D5: D20 when any data has been changed from C3.

Is there any way out please?

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: Yes, & I have been searching for any idea of scripts. Till not found :(